# Lag in MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

We have 1 master(x data centre) 2 slave(Y data centre) servers replicating over cross data centres. Sometimes in slave1 if we executes show slave status\G then seconds behind master is showing as '0' within a moment it is showing '1000+' seconds delay.We have checked master log file in master side(mysql-bin.008276) and slave side(mysql-bin.008270) . But in slave2 we couldn't see this issue. slave2 is working fine.

I would request you to check this scenario and give me a solution to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For more than a decade I have seen `Seconds_behind_master` (and the metric that preceded it) flip-flop between 0 (or near zero) and some large number (even much larger than 1000).  I have failed to see a pattern and failed to devise a test case.

On the positive side, I strongly feel that it is a fluke and can be ignored.  It usually went away after a few hours.